# I sent 1 ETH to an ICO, tx receipt failed, value (Cancelled)

Tags: erc-20, ico, coinbase, receipts

I sent 1 ETH to an ICO today without reading instructions. I sent it from my Coinbase account, so the ERC-20 cannot be retrieved on my end without Coinbase being super cool and sending them to me.

**Question:**

it is showing up as TX Receipt Fail and Value (Cancelled). Is there a chance it will show. Sick up into my Coinbase wallet so I can do this properly? 
Thank you for your help in advanced.

---

[*Link to tx overview at Etherscan*](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x002b287c82b092ce23ebfbb6eb6c861f4cf1415926957cd2e3c18a758ba054d1)

[image: TX Receipt Failed, Value cancelled?]

Comment: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x002b287c82b092ce23ebfbb6eb6c861f4cf1415926957cd2e3c18a758ba054d1

Comment: I had the exact same problem and reported it to coinbase a month ago. I still have not received an answer. Should I give up hope?

Answer (score 2):

If the transaction failed then you will not lose the 1 ether value, the only cost is the fee (0.00084184 Ether in this case).

You should [**NOT**](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2829461-altcoins-and-icos) use your coinbase account (or any other exchange for that matter) to interact with smart contracts. Coinbase may not hold a separate account with your funds in, they are likely pooled together in an account with many other people (much like a regular bank).

You should first send the ether to a wallet outside of a coinbase, then interact with the ICO smart contract. [Here](https://blockgeeks.com/how-to-setup-an-ethereum-wallet-and-buy-a-custom-token-a-guide-for-coinbase-users/) is a link with a decent enough tutorial for this.

Comment: Thank you, I've learned the hard way. But lesson learned. I really appreciate your feedback.